# Using Google Cloud Storage with Golang on Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage

I have been struggling with understanding how to properly use GCS on the App Engine using Go. I've read a few stack posts mentioning that the Go App Engine Development Server does not emulate the GCS. **Is this still the case?** I have been able to store objects to my actual default GCS when I construct my client using this code:

```
ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    jsonKey, err := ioutil.ReadFile("path/to/json.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(
        jsonKey,
        storage.ScopeFullControl,
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx, cloud.WithTokenSource(conf.TokenSource(ctx)))
```

Is this the preferred way of working with cloud storage on the App Engine?

I ask because I'm confused why some of the sample app engine code does not work properly. For instance, I was attempting to follow the code in this example (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/blob/master/examples/storage/appengine/app.go#L73). You'll notice that building the storage client simply uses

```
client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
```

Using this sample code I get a `googleapi: Error 401: Invalid Credentials, authError` error. Is this an error or am I doing something wrong? Which way should I be accessing cloud storage from a Go app engine application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled getting GCS to work with app engine also. I encountered conflicting documentation between using PEM and JSON keys. I put [this presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/14NA_G-Wv5aTrRYqti5HIt3oie-wXLBSkkAt3ljEO2y0/edit?usp=sharing) together to discuss this issue and teach people how to use GCS with app engine.

I was able to get GCS working with app engine. Here is [working GCS app engine code](https://github.com/GoesToEleven/GolangTraining/tree/master/59_appengine-GCS-storage).

I also gave a talk detailing all of this - there are two or three videos in [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSak_q1UXfPp2VwUQ4ZdUVJdMO6pfi5v_) detailing GCS and app engine.

Comment: Thanks Todd! I've been going through your material and I see that the cloud/storage lib has been updated. In your examples, you're using storage.NewWriter() which now doesn't exist. Have you been able to store objects locally? I recall with the Python runtime, objects were stored in the blobstore to simulate uploading to GCS. Does the Go runtime have this? Ideally, I'd like to not store test data to a real bucket.

Comment: Storing test data to a real bucket was the only way I found to do it. I'm disappointed to here NewWriter is deprecated!